# Django: URL error in category model

Tags: python, django

I created a simple category model. The

models

I created are as follows. Where do I make mistakes in these model files? Thanks for your help.

**models.py** The code I added to the file is as follows.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    category_desc = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('category_name',)
    verbose_name = 'category'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('article:categories', args=[self.slug])

def __str__(self):
    return self.category_name
```

**views.py** The code I added to the file is as follows.

```
def article_category(request, category_slug):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    article = Article.objects.filter( article_status='published')
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        article = article.filter(category=category)
    template = 'article/category.html'
    context = {'article': article}
return render(request, template, context)
```

url.py

```
url(r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', article_category, name='article_category'),
```

**index.html** The code I added to the file is as follows.

```
<a href="{{ articles.article_category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ article.article_category }}</a>
```

Comment: show full error stack please

Comment: There is no error just the slug area browser does not appear. Thanks u.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the non-sens `categories` variable in your view if you don't use it.

You can't call the `.filter()` method on your instance.
Change:

```
if category_slug:
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
    article = article.filter(category=category)
```

to:

```
if category_slug:
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
    article = Article.objects.filter(article_status='published', category=category)
```

You **have** to provide a url slug, that condition is useless anyway.

The `article` variable is a list with all of the entries that pass those filters. It must be `articles`.

What `index.html` has to do with your view, if you render the `article/category.html` ?

Why you render the `article/category.html`, if you want to display all articles filtered by that category?

Why aren't you using `ForeignKey` for this kind of relation.

If it's a list of articles, as I said, in your template you should have something like this (supposing you renamed `article` with `articles`):

```
{% for article in articles %}
    <a href="{{ article.get_absolute_url }}">{{ article.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

You haven't showed the Article model, so I supposed that there's `.get_absolute_url` and `.name`.

Ask me if you haven't understood something.